# this PHP code functions in XAMPP but AZURE shows code in browser

Tags: php, azure, xampp

```
<?php
require_once('functions.php');

//display links from xml
$links = simple_load_file('links.xml');
foreach($links as $link){
    $name = $link['name'];
    $ref = $link->loc;
    echo "<a href='".$ref."' class='navigation'>".$name."</a>";
}
//Display login boxes if user hasnt logged in
if((!isset($_SESSION['validUser'])) ||  ($_SESSION['validUser'] != true))
{
?>
//code for showing boxes.....
```

In the browser, it displays the folowing ;

```
loc; echo "    ".$name."   ";} //Display loginboxes.........all the way to != true)) { ?>
```

When I test this on XAMPP locally it works as intended, but using Azure it produces this.
It appears as if it's reading the '->' as a closing tag for my php.  Anyne encounter something like this?

Comment: Presumably Azure isn't configured to run PHP.

Comment: Can you confirm you mean simplexml_load_file and that xampp doesn't alias that function for convenience?

Comment: Could you also share what service in Windows Azure you're using to serve up your PHP App?

Comment: I too am assuming it's a PHP configuration issue.  However the Azure service is a .php web page service.  Wouldnt you assume it's already configured?  
My code was mistyped.  it's meant to read simplexml...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I never did get to find the exact problem, as the project was abandoned.  however, as suggested it is most likely a configuration issue from within Windows Azure.